# Matching variable string in XML tag by XSLT regex

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSLT world and I want to know how can I match string like `<mml:mtable class="ccvccvcvc">` actually I want to match the variable text `ccvccvcvc` every time and copy it to use in the conversion. 
The final result should be like:

1. Input string: `<mml:mtable class="xxx">`
2. Output string:`<xsl:text>\begin{array}{xxx}</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>\end{array}</xsl:text>`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="mml:mtable[@class]">
  <xsl:text>\begin{array}{</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>
  <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:text>\end{array}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an attribute so you can use  in the mml:table context.

Answer (score 0):

Your input "string" isn't a string, it's an XML element node. And your "output string" isn't a string, it's a fragment of XSLT program text. So I think your reference to regular expressions in the title suggests you are are confused about the XSLT processing model. Remember that XSLT is processing a tree of nodes as input to produce a tree of nodes as output.

I think Martin has probably guessed correctly what you need to do, but I suspect there may be a few gaps in your understanding of XSLT that you need to fix before you can get this working.

Comment: thank you for your response Michael. I told you before that i am new to XSLT world and i have too much to learn and what you say is perfect and professional answer thank you again.